# What is the regex for url validation in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

URL validation checks if a given text is a URL or not. Such checks are often performed when a user has to enter a URL on a web form. To ensure that the entered text corresponds to a URL, I tried to implement the regex like this

```
regexurl = “((http|https)://)(www.)?” + “[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#?&//=]{2,256}\\.[a-z]” + “{2,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#?&//=]*)”
```

But I am getting error, Please help where I am being wrong
Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to escape the `//` of `https://` (should be '\/\/')

Comment: BTW, If you don't have special reason, it would be better for reusing the regex which is well tested by the community (i.e. find one covered by unit test on Github) .

Comment: Url validation has nothing to do with react native

Answer (score 3):

If your runtime supports it, the better way of validating URLs is using the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) constructor. You can then use the parsed object to verify parts of it separately. For example, to check if something is a valid HTTP(s) URL:

```js
function isValidHttpUrl(s) {
  let url;
  try {
    url = new URL(s);
  } catch (e) { return false; }
  return /https?/.test(url.protocol);
}

isValidHttpUrl("banana"); // false, not a URL
isValidHttpUrl("http://example.com"); // true, is an HTTP URL
isValidHttpUrl("ftp://example.com"); // false, wrong protocol
```

Comment: It's not reliable. a string like 'https:fgnfxn gf.com.comsfgfgfsag' passed the validation (with a space & no slashes after the protocol

Comment: @nickornotto `isValidHttpUrl('https:fgnfxn gf.com.comsfgfgfsag')` returns false for me, what platform are you on?

Comment: This is what I get: Error: URL.protocol is not implemented

Comment: @bieboebap You don't mention what platform you're using, but it's probably a bit old, looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#browser_compatibility we can see that  `URL.protocol` has been implemented since 2016 for all runtimes they list. If you can't bump it (and don't find a suitable polyfill), this solution will sadly not work.

Have you tried googling the error message? I get several hits which may be relevant to you (for example `react-native-url-polyfill`).

Comment: yeah thanks, I found the 3th party libraries (like react-native-url-polyfill), but I did a workaround rather than try it out.